# How to close current browser tab?

Tags: java, spring, browser, vaadin, vaadin7

How do I close the current browser tab? The following aren't working.

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("window.close();");
```

or

```
UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(window);
```

or

```
window.close();
```

Comment: What code isn't working?

Comment: All versions aren't working.

Comment: Try to look here, Yury http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839601/close-the-browser-window-in-vaadin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Window appointmentWindow = getApplication().getWindow(NATIVE_WINDOW_NAME);
if (appointmentWindow != null) {
   getApplication().removeWindow(appointmentWindow);
}
```

Source: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/235330

Comment: how is this accepted answer? It does not work with vaadin 7 since vaadin 7 uses `UI` for top level window

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
gBrowser.removeCurrentTab();
```

Comment: Where did you find "removeCurrentTab()" method?

Comment: maybe here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Closing_a_tab or https://www.google.com/search?q=gBrowser+removeCurrentTab